# Bootstrap components and SMACSS/BEM methodologies

Tags: web-development, clean-code, css, bootstrap

I have no enough experience in web development and I need advice from more experienced developers.

I have been exploring `SMACSS and BEM` methodologies for a few weeks, and I like them, it makes really pretty and structured `CSS` code with reusable components.

I am building personal web-site, I have used free template for starting point (because it looks nice), and have started to refactor code from plain ugly `CSS` to modular `CSS` considering `SMACSS and BEM` approaches, keeping UI look similarly.

As most of `Bootstrap templates` this template uses bootstrap components a lot.

Here is an problematic part of the page.

```
<header id="header" class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!--Navigation menu bootstrap module-->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="custom-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home-intro">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .container -->
    </nav>
</header><!-- End Navigation -->
```

This is `navbar` component from bootstrap framework. But you may notice one weird thing here `navbar-custom`.

And CSS for this class

```
.navbar-custom {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-custom,
.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-custom ul li a span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid $color-primary;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px double #ddd;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  @include transition-properties($defaultTransitionProperties);
}

.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #282828;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 1.4em;
  padding-bottom: 1.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li.active > a {
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: $color-secondary;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.navbar-custom .nav .open > a,
.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: $color-font--root;
}
```

For me personally after diving into `SMACSS/BEM` all these class nested selectors look really ugly, and I want to get rid of them.
`last-child, li:hover > a > ...` Brrrr.
But there is another problem, this class (`navbar-custom`) is used just to override default `bootstrap styles`.

I also had a look at bootstrap components sources, unfortunately the same situation here, a lot of highly nested selectors. I understand that `bootstrap` is used for different needs and a lot of projects, but is it worth it ? To use `ugly selectors` for bootstrap components, and override them inside main css ?

Even from performance point of view as far as I know browsers read selectors right to left.

Furthermore, I found similar questions on stack overflow, where developers suggesting to get rid of `Bootstrap` in production.

So all in all my question is, is it good practice to use `Bootstrap component` or it will be much better if I create my own components and use them in my web-project. I am thinking about getting read of all bootstrap stuff except grid system.

Please share your thoughts about that, any help will be highly appreciated.